# adding a success message to a html form with php

Tags: php, forms

I´m tring to add a success message to my form after you click submit, but i dont know how, i have tried different code from different websites, but they dont work with my code. What line do i need to add to this code please?

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact"> 
         <h1>Contact-me!</h1> 
         <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
        </div>
         <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" value="SEND MESSAGE">Submit</button>
          <div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email_from = '';
$email_subject = "New Form Submission";
$email_body = "User Name: $name.\n".
                "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                    "User Message: $message.\n";
$to = "";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

Comment: `echo "Success, you've done it!";`, or `echo "<marquee>Success, you've done it!</marquee>";`, or even just close the PHP block and output any HTML you want... `?><marquee>Success, you've done it!</marquee>`.. Your email also is XSS injectable.

Comment: use session to display message on index.html

Comment: read up on [email header injection](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/email-header-injection/) your code is vulnerable

Comment: Thank you @user3783243 and Vicky for your answers, i tried to put a message **echo** but its not showing after clicking submit. im probably writing it wrong, i will learn about **session** and see if it works (i dont know php yet, just want my form to work so i copied from a tutorial), php i on my list:)

Comment: You won't actually be able to use session data on an HTML page. You'd need to use the PHP extension.. or modify server handlers to process PHP on html extensions. Please update question to show current code you are working with.